# Removing the path name of the data when plotting in gnuplot

Tags: path, gnuplot

I am relatively new to gnuplot and I am trying to plot some data and save it to a png file for a report. I am running gnuplot from a java-program using exec("gnuplot") but whenever I try to read data from a file and plot it, the plot contains the full path name of the datafile and prints it over part of my plot.

This makes the plot look rather ugly and unfit for my report. Is there a command or something that I can use to remove the path name or do I have to use Photoshop to render it away manually after generating a .png?

Comment: What gnuplot code do you use to provide the plot?

Comment: Do you mean the structure of the data-files, the actual java-code I use to call gnuplot or just the commands I give gnuplot?

Comment: The java code is written like this:
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gnuplot");
OutputStream s = process.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(s);
Then I write something along the lines of this to the OutputStreamWriter: "set terminal pngcairo size 500,500; set output "\image.png"\;  plot "\ path \" \n"

The data file is basically just a .dat file with 2 numbers on each line seperated with a tab

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The filename is the default title. If you do not want it to be shown, just turn it off:

```
plot "/path/to/file" notitle
```

Comment: Thanks! The weird part is that when I tried using the set title command, I would get a new title positioned at the top of the plot, over the coordinate system while the filename was still displayed lower on the picture, over parts of the plot.

Comment: `set title` sets the title of the whole picture. `plot ... title` sets the title for that particular plot and defaults to the filename of function being plotted.